# how to pass variable from one method to another within same class

Tags: javascript, class, fetch, modularity

I am trying to create modular code in JS and having trouble passing a variable with values to another method within the same class. I see result as '' right now. Please help!

```js
class foodApp {
  
  constructor() {
     this.getjsondata = ''
  }
  

  fetchData() {
      return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const result = JSON.stringify(data);
            this.getjsondata = result;
      })
  }
  
 displayHTML() {
    return console.log(this.getjsondata)
  }

}

new foodApp().displayHTML();
```

Comment: There's no call to `fetchData()`

Comment: I did that - still empty string

Comment: Asynchronous != synchronous. You ordered a pizza online and are surprised your plate is still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchData` is an async function and it will return a promise. you have to handle the promise.

**Try the below code.**

```js
class FoodApp {
  constructor() {
    this.getjsondata = "";
  }

  fetchData() {
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const result = JSON.stringify(data);
        this.getjsondata = result;
      });
  }

  displayHTML() {
    return this.getjsondata;
  }
}

let foodApp = new FoodApp();

(async function() {
  await foodApp.fetchData();
  console.log(foodApp.displayHTML());
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want fetchData to always run with every instance, which I think you might, include the function contents inside the constructor instead of in a separate method. Otherwise when you first call displayHTML the fetch hasn't happened yet.

```
constructor() {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const result = JSON.stringify(data);
            this.getjsondata = result;
      })
  }
```